# Jquery not loading on main landing page, but is on internal pages

Tags: jquery

Site is running on Skadate9 ( smarty.net v2 )

www.datehero.com

I have checked the details of both headers for each section I do not see any thing that is loading differently for the index vs the default.

index:

```
<div id="page_canvas">
{component PageHeader}
<div id="content">
{literal}
<style>
    .page_header {
        background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
        margin: 0px;
        height: 35px;
        width: auto;
        padding: 0px 0px 20px;
    }
</style>
{/literal}`
```

Default internal pages:

```
    {* default canvas *}

<div id="page_canvas">
        {ads pos='top'}
        {component PageHeader}
        <div class="content">
        <div class="side-Bar">
        {if !isset($sidebar) || $sidebar}
            {component PageSidebar}
        {/if}
        </div>

    <div class="right-content">
        <div class="con-wrap">
        {ads pos='middle'}
        {component GroupBriefInfo}
        {component BreadCrumb}
        <div class="sub-menu">
        {component NavigationSubMenu level=1}
        </div>      
        <div class="adsen">
            {literal}
                <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                <!-- date hero 2 -->
                <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
                     data-ad-client="ca-pub-1054861330472333"
                     data-ad-slot="1068095604"></ins>
                <script>
                (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                </script>
            {/literal}
        </div>    
        <h1 id="page_content_header">{$content_header}</h1>
```

you can see there is a little more code in the default but it is nothing really to effect the jquery. I am at a bit of a lost here, why it would not work on the main landing page vs the others.

Comment: jQuery is being loaded for me from the link, tested in console and running `jQuery.fn.jquery` give me `"1.11.3"`

Comment: Same here. There are other issues with the page. Mainly missing files. I did see an error related to a jQuery plugin. `jQuery collection is empty`

Comment: -Humble.Rumble :  none of those errors would really effect jquery.  but i fixed everything but the missing 404, which is due to the platform.

Comment: -pcnate thanks can you give details more? see the inner pages load the same code, and has the same effects, that work there.. but do not on the landing page.